# How can I render a list of triangle mesh coordinates?

Tags: 3d, 3d-model

I have a file that I think represents a series of coordinates for a triangle mesh in 3D space. The first few lines look like this:

`-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,15.312572 2.584137,2.443666,12.413793 
-0.000000,-18.758621,12.413793 2.090611,-18.443666,10.622249 2.090610,-18.443666,14.205337 
-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 2.584137,2.443666,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,9.515014 
-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,9.515014 -2.090611,2.443666,10.622249`

The rest of the file (over 47 kB) follows this pattern.

I want to be able to see the model represented by this data. Is there some text I can wrap the entire thing with to make it viewable in a program like MeshLab?

For the record: I wasn't sure if I should ask this here or on SuperUser.

Comment: If you planned to write some code using OpenGL or similar to render this, then this is a good place to ask.  Otherwise you could try [superuser](http://superuser.com/), but you may have more luck on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you writing code to solve this problem? If not it probably shouldn't be on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, but it looks like each line is the (x,y,z) coordinates for three vertices that make up a triangle?

If so, this format is very compatible with the STL file format. Once you convert it to the STL format, there are many viewers to visualize the data.
There are STL writers in many different languages, just perform a google search for an example.